# Error when creating allocation with LLVM IR Builder CreateAlloca

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have the following line of code throwing an exception in LLVM IR C++ API:

```
AllocaInst *allocate = builder->CreateAlloca(objectType);
```

When run, it throws the following exception:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x38)
  * frame #0: 0x00000001000302fa birdd`llvm::BasicBlock::getModule() const + 4
    frame #1: 0x0000000100003018 birdd`llvm::IRBuilderBase::CreateAlloca(llvm::Type*, llvm::Value*, llvm::Twine const&) [inlined] llvm::BasicBlock::getModule(this=<unavailable>) at BasicBlock.h:117:68 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x0000000100003013 birdd`llvm::IRBuilderBase::CreateAlloca(this=0x0000000101102230, Ty=0x0000000101801000, ArraySize=0x0000000000000000, Name=0x00007ffeefbff038) at IRBuilder.h:1598 [opt]
```

This gave me an indication that the getModule() is returning an invalid pointer. Funny thing is the `builder` and the `module` share the same `LLVMContext`.

So I decided to run it through `verifyModule` as follows:

```
verifyModule(*builder->GetInsertBlock()->getModule());
```

The same error. But when I access the `module` object directly, it appears to be fine.

Here is my initialisation code:

```
static LLVMContext context;
std::unique_ptr<Module> module = std::make_unique<Module>("Main", context);
std::unique_ptr<IRBuilder<>> builder = std::make_unique<llvm::IRBuilder<>>(context);
```

I'm stuck. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`IRBuilder` will not be able to pick up `Module` from context (same context may be used by multiple modules) and in any case `Module` alone would not be enough - builder also needs to know the point at which instructions should be inserted. So you'd either need to provide it with a `BasicBlock` at construction time or set it explicitly via

```
builder->SetInsertPoint(BB);
```

or even

```
builder->SetInsertPoint(Inst);
```

if you want to insert not at BB's end.

A few side notes:

1. I'd suggest to follow LLVM's coding style of upper-cased variable names (this would make maintenance easier later on).
2. Builders are cheap to create so most often they are just created as local variables in functions that need them:

```
IRBuilder<> IRB;
```